# PHP/MYSQL compare dates

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a date in php formatted like this:

```
Fri May 01 2015 17:25:00 GMT +0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

And Im trying to compare it to a mysql DATETIME field:

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s e+", $start);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ax_timestamps WHERE $date1 < datetimefeild ORDER BY id ASC";
```

But when it executes it returns 0 results even though based in the input and elements in the database it should pull results.

example of data in the datetimefeild feild:

```
2015-05-16 07:44:56
```

The date is being passed to php via ajax post from jQuery datepicker which is setup like this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
var start = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", $('#datepicker').val());
```

Comment: Are you sure the name of the field is `datetimefeild` and not `datetimefield`?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a the date in wrong format (as string). You should first convert it to datetime type in the where clause using str_to_date() function.

Example:

```
SELECT str_to_date('2015-05-01 08:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')
```

Applying it, your $sql string would become:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ax_timestamps WHERE datetimefeild < str_to_date('".$date1."', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') ORDER BY id ASC";
```

**EDIT:** this also works:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ax_timestamps WHERE datetimefeild < '".$date1."' ORDER BY id ASC";
```

Comment: Neither seem to work correctly. They both return results from the sample input but when I put a date that is later than the dates in the database it still returns them when it shouldnt. E.g. Fri May 31 2015 17:25:00 GMT +0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

Comment: I still think that you need to convert your datetime to the format of MYSQL, which is somehow as i mentioned above. On the other hand, i see another problem of the date picker in your example uses "yy-mm-dd" which lacks the time part.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
Fri May 01 2015 17:25:00 GMT +0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

isn't a valid date/time format. You need to have only

```
Fri May 01 2015 17:25:00 GMT +0100
```

so you can do this

```
$date1 = new DateTime(substr($start, 0, -20));
```

and

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ax_timestamps WHERE {$date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')} < datetimefeild ORDER BY id ASC";
```